# WPF circular progress bar: how to move hard coded property

Tags: wpf, user-controls, geometry

In my application i am using `Circular progress-bar`.
So in case i want to use this controller in several places how can i set the `Radius` property in my `XAML` instead of using the current value which is all the time 100 ? (in class `CircularProgressBar`)

This is my `Circular progress bar`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="myApplication.CircularProgressBar"
             x:Name="userControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Path x:Name="pathRoot" Stroke="{Binding SegmentColor, ElementName=userControl}"
              StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness, ElementName=userControl}" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="100" Width="100">
                <Path.Data>
                    <PathGeometry>
                        <PathGeometry.Figures>
                            <PathFigureCollection>
                                <PathFigure x:Name="pathFigure">
                                    <PathFigure.Segments>
                                        <PathSegmentCollection>
                                            <ArcSegment x:Name="arcSegment" SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                                        </PathSegmentCollection>
                                    </PathFigure.Segments>
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathFigureCollection>
                        </PathGeometry.Figures>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

---

```
public partial class CircularProgressBar : UserControl
    {
        public CircularProgressBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Angle = (Percentage * 360) / 100;
            RenderArc();
        }

        public int Radius
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(RadiusProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RadiusProperty, value); }
        }

        public Brush SegmentColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(SegmentColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SegmentColorProperty, value); }
        }

        public int StrokeThickness
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty, value); }
        }

        public double Percentage
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(PercentageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PercentageProperty, value); }
        }

        public double Angle
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(AngleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AngleProperty, value); }
        }

        public enum Modes
        {
            Full = 360,
            Half = 180,
            Intermediate = 250
        }

        public Modes CircularMode
        {
            get { return (Modes)GetValue(CircularModeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CircularModeProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CircularModeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CircularMode", typeof(Modes), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(Modes.Full));

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Percentage.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PercentageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Percentage", typeof(double), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(65d, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPercentageChanged)));

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StrokeThickness.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeThicknessProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeThickness", typeof(int), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(1));

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SegmentColor.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SegmentColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SegmentColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)));

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Radius.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Radius", typeof(int), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(100, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Angle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Angle", typeof(double), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(120d, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));

        private static void OnPercentageChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            CircularProgressBar circle = sender as CircularProgressBar;
            circle.Angle = (circle.Percentage * (int)circle.CircularMode) / 100;
        }

        private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            CircularProgressBar circle = sender as CircularProgressBar;
            circle.RenderArc();
        }

        public void RenderArc()
        {
            Point startPoint = new Point(Radius, 0);
            Point endPoint = ComputeCartesianCoordinate(Angle, Radius);
            endPoint.X += Radius;
            endPoint.Y += Radius;

            pathRoot.Width = Radius * 2 + StrokeThickness;
            pathRoot.Height = Radius * 2 + StrokeThickness;
            pathRoot.Margin = new Thickness(StrokeThickness, StrokeThickness, 0, 0);

            bool largeArc = Angle > 180.0;

            Size outerArcSize = new Size(Radius, Radius);

            pathFigure.StartPoint = startPoint;

            if (startPoint.X == Math.Round(endPoint.X) && startPoint.Y == Math.Round(endPoint.Y))
                endPoint.X -= 0.01;

            arcSegment.Point = endPoint;
            arcSegment.Size = outerArcSize;
            arcSegment.IsLargeArc = largeArc;
        }

        private Point ComputeCartesianCoordinate(double angle, double radius)
        {
            // convert to radians
            double angleRad = (Math.PI / 180.0) * (angle - 90);
            double x = radius * Math.Cos(angleRad);
            double y = radius * Math.Sin(angleRad);
            return new Point(x, y);
        }
    }
```

This is the hard code value:

```
// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Radius.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Radius", typeof(int), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(100, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));
```

Comment: Where is the hardcoded value in your XAML? Which property are you referring to?

Comment: Please see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100 is just the default value of the `Radius` property. You should be able to set it to any int value you want just like you set any other dependency property:

```
<local:CircularProgressBar Radius="200" ... />
```